# Regex replace with Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex, find-and-replace

In my XML file there are lots of sub strings starting with STDSUP- and then three digits. For example: STDSUP-123.  I would like to replace the STDSUP with CCDA. There are some sub strings where STUSUP- is following by non-numeric characters. I don't want to change them. So, I used STDSUP-\d\d\d in the find field and CCDA-\d\d\d in the replace with field. But the three digits are getting replaces with ddd. I want to replace only STDSUP and want the digits unchanged.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Starting in Notepad++ version 6, you can also separate the match with PCRE-style capture groups:

> Find What: (STDSUP-)(\d\d\d)
>
> Replace with: CCDA-$2

Comment: -1: This does not work in Notepad++ - it replaces the digit string the OP wanted to preserve with `$2`. See [this screencap](http://i.imgur.com/XtAcSri.png).

Comment: It works in Notepad++ starting in version 6. see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11970406/1521193

Comment: Ah, my bad. I was still running the old version. Edited and undownvoted :)

Answer (score 1):

To keep part of the string intact, you want to use a group in your "find" expression and a backreference in your "replace" one.

Find: `STDSUP-(\d\d\d)`
Replace: `CCDA-\1`

[image: screencap]